# What does reslen and other means in mongodb log?

Tags: mongodb

```
database.tablebusiness query: { LongitudeLatitude: { $nearSphere: [ 106.772835, -6.186753 ], $maxDistance: 0.04498373205078301 }, Prominent: { $gte: 15 }, indexContents: { $all: [ /^aru/, /^op/ ] } } ntoreturn:20 ntoskip:80 nscanned:100 nreturned:20 reslen:1147 1927ms
```

it seems that ntoreturn means number to return. ntoskip is numbers to skip. nscanned seem to be the sum of the 2.

What is reslen?

I search google with no answer. What site explain what reslen is?

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-UnderstandingtheOutput

Comment: Who downvotes and why? You think it's that obvious what the profiling tool is and how it has anything to do with log? Can you get that through google easily?

Comment: The latter.  I fed google with "mongodb reslen", and in the very first hit I searched for reslen.  All this in 30 seconds.  Without knowing a bit about MongoDB.

Comment: I saw many documents containing both mongodb and reslen, most simply come from someone copying and pasting it's log. Somehow the first result is what works for you. I forget query I searched but that result is not in first 10. Also how do users, searching for mongodb reslen knows that that the site will explain about reslen? Most other results don't.

Comment: without checking those search results you'll never know...  I've just checked the _first_ one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reslen` is the query result length in bytes.  From the profiler docs here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/